# Resetting the bounds of UILabels when view is loaded gives a glitch (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I have a UIViewController with a .xib having 2 UILables named "LblA" and "LblB". Lets call this ViewController "A". The bounds or the positioning of LblA and LblB depend on @property's called lblABounds and lblBBounds respectively. If the values of lblABounds and lblBounds are not set, lblA and lblB are positioned to the default bounds as they are placed using Interface Builder in .xib. The new bounds obtained from lblABounds and lblBBounds for lblA and lblB are set in ViewDidLoad() function.

There is a another UIViewController (Lets call it "B") that loads "A". It first calls the init of "A" to retrieve an object. Then using that object, it sets the values of lblABounds and lblBBounds. And then just animates and load the ViewConroller by adding it as a subview of "B". All works fine except...

**The glitch:**

B animates and flips to show A. But while it is flipping, for a glimpse, the lblA and lblB are positioned to their default locations but as soon as theanimation is over they just *poof* move to the location set by the values of lblABounds and lblBounds.

**Suspected reason of this glitch:**

As the position of lblA and lblB obtained from the values of lblABounds and lblBBounds are set in ViewDidLoad. So while it is animating, the view has actually not been loaded and ViewDidLoad has not been called so ,for a glimpse, the lblA and lblB are positioned to the default location. As soon as the view is done with the animation and  ViewDidLoad is called, lblA and lblB disappear-appear from the default location to the location set by the values of lblABounds and lblBBounds.

**The fixes I have tried but didn't work**

- Setting the new bounds of lblA and lblB in init(). Nothing happens :S None of the code gets executed.

...Please help. I hope I explained well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

You may also want to try loading the view before you add it as a subview. This will force the view did load method to be called and set the label positions before the animation is called. To force loading a view controller for view, you need to request the view property

```
viewController.view
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: OMG! It got fixed! Thank you very much Eytan! You are awesome. I wish I could give you more vote ups.

I just called the viewController.view before starting the animation and it got fixed.